# Is it permissible to use store bought milk in shaligrama aradhana?

Tags: vishnu, shaligrama

The dharma shastras have regulations on what type of milk is sattvic and can be consumed:

> [Manusmriti](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200382.html) -
> **The milk of the cow that has not passed its ten days**, as also that of the camel and of one-hoofed animals and of sheep; the milk of the irregular cow, **as also the milk of the cow without her calf. [are all prohibited]**

This rule is universally found in all dharma shastras. But as we know, modern dairy practices do not follow these rules. The cow is milked as soon as it gives birth, and is separated from her calf by being hooked up to a milking machine.

Vedanta Desikan also cites a verse from scripture in his grantha [Rahasyatrayasara](https://archive.org/details/rahasyatrayasaraofsrivedantadesikaengmrrajagopalaayyangar1946ocr/page/n362/mode/1up?view=theater) about the consequence of drinking prohibited milk:

> He who eats white brinjals (eggplant), kommatti, **cheese (or curds) made from the milk of a cow within ten days of its calving**, the bulb of the lotus — **he will never think in his last moments of Bhagavan, the Lord of the world**

So considering the last line shows how much this kind of dairy displeases lord Vishnu, it doesn't make sense to use store bought milk in abhishekham for Vishnu during his poojas. In fact, it is probably also SINFUL.

So are there scripturally sanctioned alternatives for what to use in abhishekham? Or this is a "kAla exception" since 99% of dairy today is like this, and many temples, mathams, and ashrams use and drink store bought milk?

Comment: According to government statistics, buffaloes contribute about 49% of milk produced in India, while cows contribute around 47%. So it is more likely that packaged milk bought from stores comes from buffaloes. Buffalo milk & its derivatives are a strict no-no in religious activities. Some brands do sell cow-milk separately but then the question arises whether that milk is pure according to scriptural standards or not. Chances of adulteration (for example mixing the scripturally sanctioned 'pure'  cow-milk with scripturally defined 'impure' cow-milk) must also be taken into consideration.

Comment: India doesn't imports milk from other countries because there blood-meal is used as fodder for livestock. Blood-meal is actually dried & proceesed blood obtained after slaughtering cows & calves for manufacturing processed beef & is used a protein-rich diet for livestock. You can substitute water for milk during abhiseka, but when it comes to food articles, I would prefer avoiding store-bought material.

Comment: @AnubrataBit Thanks for the comment. Just one thing: "Buffalo milk & its derivatives are a strict no-no in religious activities." - Buffalo is permitted according to the Manusmriti 5.9: "That of all wild animals, **except the buffalo**; the milk of females (women) and all soured substances should be avoided."

Comment: @AnubrataBit "blood-meal" - I live in the US and this is a big issue how they abuse cows.

Comment: in that case, you have completely avoid milk for religious activities while residing in USA.

Comment: @AnubrataBit Yeah but the problem is cooked rice (annam) has to be eaten with ghee, and it has to be offered to Bhagavan as prasadam before eating. But the ghee is impure, so then I can't offer annam, and then this means I can't eat annam because we can't eat food that is not offered to bhagavan. This means I have to live off strawberries plucked from my backyard garden!

Comment: @AnubrataBit So there is a dilemma.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139583/discussion-between-anubrata-bit-and-ikshvaku).

Comment: you can buy imported cow ghee from indian stores

Comment: @mar Do those ghee companies in India follow the 10 day rule?

Comment: @mar Either way, that's probably the best choice.

Comment: everything in life is on a scale.. not binary 0 or 1. even dharma/punya or adharma/paap is like that. the closer you get to 100% dharma, the closer you get to 100% punya. from perspective of 100, both 0 & 99 are same. but you can't get to 100 without first going from 0 thru 1 thru 50 thru 99. saying "it is hard to get to 100, can only do 99, and that's anyway same as 50 cos neither is 100" - means that one will definitely stay at 50

Comment: @অনু I guess this is why Manu states Brahmins and other Dvijas should live in Aryavrata and lands fit for sacrifice. In my opinion theirs simply no way to avoid it. You either have to do one or the other.